# Как объеденить многомерный и одномерный список, чтобы получить многомерный список соединеный по условию

Tags: python, list

У меня есть 2 списка, один одномерный, другой многомерный.
Нужно соединить 2 списка и получить другой список, чтобы элементы первого, соответствовали значениям второго

Первый список

```
[январь,февраль,март,апрель]
```

Второй список

```
[[февраль,200],[апрель,400],[март,300]]
```

Что должно получится

```
[[февраль,200],[март,300],[апрель,400]]
```

Comment: не очень похоже на объединить. а сортировка по числовому значению вам не подойдёт ?

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял:

```py
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
lst2 = [['b', 200], ['c', 400], ['d', 300]]
lst3 = sorted(lst2, key=lambda x: lst1.index(x[0]))
```

UPD [@GrAnd](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/433855/grand):

```py
lst1 = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
lst2 = [['b', 200], ['c', 400], ['d', 300]]
lst3 = sorted(filter(lambda x : x[0] in lst1, lst2), key=lambda x: lst1.index(x[0]))
```

Comment: Если вдруг `lst2` содержит элементы отсутствующие в `lst1`, то на `index()` крэшнется. На этот случай можно добавить `filter()`.   `lst3 = sorted(filter(lambda x : x[0] in lst1, lst2), key=lambda x: lst1.index(x[0]))`